Force WMS source to use unsecure URL
This is related to my previous question. The issue is that when the app is deployed,
proxy URL is changed from HTTP to HTTPS and our proxy server is not secured. Is there a way to force the WMS source to navigate to not secured URL from secured server?
WMS TileLayers configuration is pretty basic:
createTileWMSLayer(): TileLayer<TileWMS> {
  this._tileLayer = new TileLayer({
    opacity: BASE_MAP_LAYER_OPACITY,
    source: new TileWMS({
      params: { LAYERS: 'osm', VERSION: '1.1.1' },
      url: 'http://IP_ADDRESS/mapproxy/service',
      // When the app is deployed, WMS is trying to reach https://IP_ADDRESS/...
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    }),
    properties: {
      id: MAP_LAYERS_ID.WMS_LAYER_ID
    }
  });
  return this._tileLayer;
}

Is there a config parameter for this in OpenLayers lib? Providing a secured proxy server might be a long run as it depends on our client decision.

The browser is doing that, not OpenLayers.  The end would need to override the security settings on their browser (for Chrome chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure).

I dreaded this answer, this won't pass. I guess there's no other way than requesting the secured proxy server.
